# QComboBox и QTableView, проблема с focus/selection при раскрытии элементов combobox

Tags: c++, qt

Я изменил стандартное отображение элементов combobox при помощи *QTableView*.

**Проблема заключается в** установке фокуса или в настройке *selection*. Я установил `QAbstractItemView::SelectRows` для `view` и это работает, когда я навожу курсор на строки *QTableView* (см. `setup_table_view` и Рис. 2).

Но когда combobox открывается и я не перемещаю курсор на элементы combobox, то тогда получается выбрана ячейка одного столбца (который определен при помощи `setModelColumn`, см. Рис. 1).

Я пробовал использовать опции `selection mode`, но безрезультатно.

Итак, **как** можно **установить выделение для всей строки**, когда combobox открывается при клике (другими словами получить результат из Рис.2 с позицией курсора из Рис. 1)?

P.S. Я изменил цвет курсора для повышения контрастности.

Pic. 1: Курсор находится на том же месте, где произошел клик.
[image: 0_1540454500496_11.PNG]

Pic. 2: Курсор был перемещен на первую строку в *QTableView*.[image: 1_1540454500496_22.PNG]

Пример кода (результат выполнения соответствует изображениям, а файл *mainwindow.h* без изменений):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QStandardItemModel *model = get_model(); // получаю модель (см. ниже)
    QTableView *cbxView = new QTableView(this);

    // задаю модель для view, чтобы установить статическую ширину столбца   
    cbxView->setModel(model); 

    setup_table_view(cbxView); // настраиваю свойства view (см. ниже)

    ui->comboBox->setModelColumn(1);
    ui->comboBox->setView(cbxView);
    ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
}

/****  Здесь настраиваю свойства для view   ****/
void setup_table_view(QTableView * view)
{
    view->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);

    // эта строка указана в описании проблемы
    view->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows); 

    view->setColumnWidth(0, 30);
    view->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    view->verticalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    view->verticalHeader()->hide();
    view->horizontalHeader()->hide();
}

/****   Пример модели для полного примера   ****/
QStandardItemModel* get_model()
{
    QString names[] = {"Alex", "Tim", "Mary", "Ben", "Nicole", "Max"};
    QString indexes[] = {"1", "3", "6", "5", "4", "2"};
    QString addresses[] = {
        "Alex address", "Tim address", "Mary address",
        "Ben address", "Nicole address", "Max address"
    };

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        model->setItem(i, 0, new QStandardItem(indexes[i]));
        model->setItem(i, 1, new QStandardItem(names[i]));
        model->setItem(i, 2, new QStandardItem(addresses[i]));
    }

    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, переопределив *showEvent* у *QTableView*. Этот [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987138/qcombobox-with-qtableview-selection-or-focus-problem-when-combobox-items-pop-up#answer-52987940) помог мне.

Я сделал что-то наподобие этого:

```
class MyTableView : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyTableView(QWidget *parent=0) : QTableView(parent) {}

protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
    {
        if (e->type() == QShowEvent::Show)
            this->selectRow(this->currentIndex().row());
    }
};
```

Comment: хорошим тоном было бы перевести ответ...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, исправился :) Привел кастомизированное решение.